# Relace nested loop with java lambda in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the following snippet:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'Heading')]")
List<WebElement> accordianContainer;
    
public void repeatClickEleInArray(List<WebElement> array, int numRepeat) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < numRepeat; j++) {
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(1000));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(accordianContainer.get(i))).click();
          }
        }
```

I replaced it with lambda but get error because wrong provided type at "get(i)"

```
    array.forEach(i -> {
      numRepeat(j -> {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(1000));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(accordianContainer.get(i))).click();
      });
    });
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `i` is not an index anymore in your second code... It's the element itself, so possibly `get(i)` got the wrong parameter type?

Comment: yes, I think so but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What's `accordianContainer`? A `List`?

Comment: yes, it's a List